# Javascript function fires on pageload instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tId;

    $(function() {
        $('#btnSign').click(function() {
            InitiatePolling();
        });
    });

    function InitiatePolling() {

        event.preventDefault();
        tId = setInterval(Poll, 1000);
    }
    function Poll() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var res = <%= PollResponse() %>;
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to write a javascript function that fires on a click event from the front end. and calls a method in the backend. the method can indeed be called, the problem here is that the function Poll() executes upon the loading of this user control. how do I prevent the function to run prematurely?

edit:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSign').click(function() {
            tId = setInterval(function() {Poll();}, 1000);

```
        function Poll(){
            var res = <%= PollResponse() %>;
        }

    });
});
```

I moved everything inside the functiuon that should fire when the button is clicked, but the line with the PollResponse() call is executed every postback anyway. maybe this is the wrong way to go about this problem, is there a safer way to call back end methods within a user control javascript?

Comment: The button btw is placed inside an asp:UpdatePanel if that information clarifies anything.

Comment: why are you using setInterval..?

Comment: I need the Poll function to run every 1 seconds. the whole procedure is not complete yet, I had just begun writing this to test if it worked to fire this function on a click event

Comment: remove `event.preventDefault();` from both of your functions, and check console for errors this code of yours has bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to subscribe to click event like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnSign", function() {
    InitiatePolling();
});
```

Comment: doesn't prevent the var res = <%= PollResponse() %>; line from being executed on every postback.

Answer (score 0):

Write the setTimeInterval this way. Otherwise the function gets executed in setTimeInterval. I know it is weird.

```
function InitiatePolling() {

        event.preventDefault();
        tId = setInterval(function(){Poll();}, 1000);
    }
```

Update:
The problem is `<%= PollResponse() %>` this statement in you code. <%%> defines that code will be executed on server when the page HTML is generated.
If you see the rendered HTML of you page on the browser you will see that it is not `res = <%= PollResponse() %>` but `res = out put of PollResponse`.

So this function is executed every time page is loaded.

If you want to make a call to server function from javascript you need to use ajax. something like this

```
function Poll() {
        event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
            url : "yourServerUrl/PollResponse",
            success : function(result){ res = result; }
         });        
    }
```

I am not aware of JS version to make asynchronous call. Please check that in the references.

Comment: done thx. but did nothing to stop my original dilemma, the Poll function gets executed in every post-back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. Below is the code that works correctly:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.btnSign').click(function() {
                Poll();
            });
        });

        function Poll() {
            debugger;            
            var res = '<%= PollResponse() %>';

            setTimeout(Poll, 2000);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSign').click(function() {
        InitiatePolling();
    });
});
```

Anyway you should use browser developer tools and add a break point inside Poll function and check Call Stack tab to see from where it is being called.

Comment: App_Web_qae5vqav.dll!ASP.signup_signup_components_bankid_sign_ascx.__Render__control1(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter __w, System.Web.UI.Control parameterContainer) Line 19 C#                          this is what's on the call stack when I put the breakpoint on the var res = <%= PollResponse() %>; line.